# Accidently removed libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 and now I can't access my computer in GUI mode

Tags: boot, bluetooth, gui

I removed the `libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64` package and my computer froze and started doing weird stuff so I tried to restart it, but now it does not boot and I get this error instead:

```
Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-110)
Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To help the community resolve your issue, please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. Thanks.